# MySQL service inside docker container not working in macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-container

I was forced to reinstall macOS Sierra because I was in the beta program for High Sierra and I get a serious crash so I downgraded the system.

This Dockerfile was working in High Sierra before the sudden crash of the system.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER XXX version 0.0.1

# Prepare Debian environment
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
# we don't need an apt cache in a container
RUN echo "Acquire::http {No-Cache=True;};" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache

# ----------------------------
# Configure supervisor
# ----------------------------
RUN apt-get update > /dev/null 2>&1 && apt-get install -y supervisor > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY files/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

## Mysql
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client > /dev/null 2>&1
#RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 1234'
#RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 1234'
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 1234' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 1234' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
RUN echo "sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE" >> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
mys
ADD files/xxx.dump /tmp/xxx.dump
ADD files/mysql_xxx.sql /tmp/mysql_xxx.sql

RUN service mysql start && \
    mysql -uroot -p1234 < /tmp/mysql_xxx.sql

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN apt-get clean

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Now, reinstalling all things I does not work, it always outputs the same error:

`Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...fail!`

To add some information, in the step where the Dockerfile stops I am starting the service to dump a database.

My system version macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29) is and my Docker version is 17.06.0-ce-mac19 (18663). Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile directly in your question, no need to use pastebin

Comment: Why are you not using the official MySQL Dockerfile and its entrypoint shell script?

Comment: As @BrianOgden mentioned you should be using original `mysql` file. Also in docker `service` command won't work as there is no init system

Comment: @BrianOgden well, I’m not using the official MySQL Dockerfile because I took this example that we use in my company and it is working well in an Ubuntu 16.04. Do you have any example with the official MySQL image and a db dump?

Comment: @xmarston sorry no I do not have an example with a db dump, I provided an answer to your question and gave an example of converting the official MySQL Dockerfile to use CentOS instead of Debian

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the official MySQL Dockerfile as your starting point. You could either just use the MySQL image itself, `FROM mysql:5.7` for your Dockerfile or you can copy the Dockerfile and the docker-entrypoint,sh from [their Github](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/0590e4efd2b31ec794383f084d419dea9bc752c4/5.7/Dockerfile) to "take control" of the MySQL image and not have any dependency on MySQL releases/changes.

I think it is a good idea to use the same OS base for all your Docker containers, you are currently using Ubuntu distro, if you do not mind or are just getting started you may want to have Debian be your OS base. I say this because the Docker images I have looked so far, Cloudbee's Jenkins, .NET Core, ASP.NET COre and MySQL all have a Debian base so I been thinking Debian is the most popular OS base for Docker images though I only have anecdotal evidence of this obviously.

My company prefers CentOS distro, so I took the official MySQL Dockerfile and [converted to work with CentOS:7](https://github.com/Sweetog/Docker-MySQL-Centos-7), it was a pain.

Comment: Ok, I accept that the best option is to use the official MySQL Dockerfile but I have not been able to configure it correctly yet... And a thought is whirling in my mind and is that I had it working perfectly previous to the system fatal crash, so I don't understand why now it is not working....